# How to ask mathematica to compute higher order derivatives evaluated at 0

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a function, let's say for example,

```
D[x^2*Exp[x^2], {x, 6}] /. x -> 0
```

And I want to replace 6 by a general integer `n`,

Or cases like the following:

```
 Limit[Limit[D[D[x /((-1 + x) (1 - y) (-1 + x + x y)), {x, 3}], {y, 5}], {x -> 0}], {y -> 0}]
```

And I want to replace 3 and 5 by a general integer `m` and `n` respectively.

How to solve these two kinds of problems in general in mma?

Many thanks.

Comment: In your first question: Do you want the derivative as an explicit  function of n, or a general expression for the n derivative?

Comment: @belisarius: I want to have an explicit function of the symbolic variable `n`. So your answer below is not better than what I gave above. It evaluates the expression for a specific value of `n`. thanks.

Comment: Simon's answer to your previous similar question should apply here too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can use SeriesCoefficient, sometimes.

```
InputForm[n! * SeriesCoefficient[x^2*Exp[x^2], {x,0,n}]]
```

Out[21]//InputForm= 
n!*Piecewise[{{Gamma[n/2]^(-1), Mod[n, 2] == 0 && n >= 2}}, 0]

```
InputForm[mncoeff = m!*n! *
  SeriesCoefficient[x/((-1+x)*(1-y)*(-1+x+x*y)), {x,0,m}, {y,0,n}]]
```

Out[22]//InputForm= 
m!*n!*Piecewise[{{-1 + Binomial[m, 1 + n]*Hypergeometric2F1[1, -1 - n, m - n, 
       -1], m >= 1 && n > -1}}, 0]

Good luck extracting limits for m, n integer, in this second case.

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: I think the Limits are for x and y

Comment: Do you know if  there is a reason behind the possibility to get a function of n in SeriesCoefficient, but not in D[f,{x,n}]?

Comment: @Belisarius (1) You'd need to take limits for m,n because plugging in integer values would give an indeterminate form. (2) I do not know why D does not handle a symbolic order of differentiation when SeriesCoefficient seems to support it. Probably a matter of typical usage. But there might be a deeper reason.

Answer (score 1):

No sure if this is what you want, but you may try:

```
D[x^2*Exp[x^2], {x, n}] /. n -> 4 /. x -> 0
```

Another way:

```
f[x0_, n_] := n! SeriesCoefficient[x^2*Exp[x^2], {x, x0, n}]  
f[0,4]  
24
```

And of course, in the same line, for your other question:

```
f[m_, n_] := 
 Limit[Limit[
   D[D[x/((-1 + x) (1 - y) (-1 + x + x y)), {x, m}], {y, n}], {x -> 
     0}], {y -> 0}]
```

These answers don't give you an explicit form for the derivatives, though.